# pop up using htmlExpand not working in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I had downloaded the following high charts files. 
stock/highstock-1.3.2.js
        stock/exporting-1.3.2.js
        highslide/highslide-4.1.8.full.min.js
        highslide/highslide-4.1.8.config.js
        http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css

I had created a graph with a popup using htmlExpand.
The code used to work, but now the pop up that comes up when clicking on the graphs does not display properly.

Following is the js fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/pX5XE/

```
hs.htmlExpand(null, {
pageOrigin: {
x: this.pageX,
y: this.pageY
},
headingText: 'Offers',
maincontentText:  "hello world",
width: 200
});
```

Regards
Joseph

Comment: Your demo doesn't work. Fix errors from console and attach required JS/CSS files.

Comment: could you send me the links to the highchart js and css files? I will add them to my demo. The highchart js and css files that I have are old. I think that is why the htmlExpand doesnt work.

Comment: All of them are available on http://code.highcharts.com and http://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/highslide.css / http://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/highslide.js

Comment: I have added the css link and js links to the js fiddle. But I am not still getting the graph. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/pX5XE/2/

Comment: You still have errors in console.. just fix them and you will get working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pX5XE/4/

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
hs.htmlExpand(null, {
headingText: 'Offers',
maincontentText:  "hello world",
width: 200
});
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.